# How to validate an ajax combobox with empty text?

Tags: asp.net, validation, combobox, ajaxcontroltoolkit

How should I validate if my `AJAX ComboBox` contains text? I have tried with the `ASP.NET RequiredFieldValidator` but it dosen't work.

Comment: Seems like this is a reported issue for the Ajax Combobox: http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/24338 The reporting users second problem are the same problem i have.

Answer (score 0):

If found a solution here: http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/24417

Had to add javascript to change the controltovalidate property for the internal textbox.

```
string script = string.Format(@"if({0}) {0}.controltovalidate = ""{1}_TextBox"";", this.reqValidator.ClientID, this.ddlCombo.ClientID);

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), string.Format("validator trick for {0}", this.ClientID), script, true);
```